# Poisson Distribution Process Control Limits

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process, quality-control

I am measuring the number of events that happen within n minute intervals for a group of 100 stores. My problem is, I am looking for a way to calculate a threshold for the acceptable number of times this event can occur within the 10 minute interval without some established boundary. Although this is a Poisson distribution can I use process control limits of 3sd? And if I use a process control does that mean my upper control limit is my threshold? And if a value exceeds how should that be interpreted?

Comment: What properties do you want your control limits to have? What makes you say it's Poisson rather than something else?

Comment: [NIST](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section3/pmc331.htm) gives advice about control charts for Poisson data. I've had decent success monitoring lower count Poisson series just by taking the square root, see [here](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2017/07/17/iaca-conference-2017-workshop-monitoring-temporal-crime-trends-for-outliers-excel/) for some reference to that work.

Comment: @Andy The NIST methods are OK for largish counts.  (They recommend a Normal approximation for large counts and variations on the square root transform for moderate counts.)  When the counts are low--when a substantial number of zeros appear in the data--then beware.

Comment: Agree @whuber. My experience with monitoring crime counts is that they need to have at least a mean of 5. I did some additional simulations of data with overdispersion [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2551472), and I found that simply adding 1 sigma tended to produce reasonable coverage, so 2*sigma for normal data ~ 3*sigma for the square roots of the overdispersed crime counts. Not perfect for sure, but appeared to limit false positives in my application to reasonable numbers.

Comment: @Glen_b the description of the problem states why it is a Poisson process.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It would need to give a reason to think that the assumptions you'd need for that to be a Poisson process hold. It says events happen in time but it doesn't establish that they should be independent or that the rate of events would be constant. If you're explicitly *assuming* they're Poisson, that's fine (if you're clear it's merely an assumption) but you seem to think that it's established that the counts will be Poisson. On the basis of what's in your question it isn't; you may find that the variance is larger than the mean with too many small values and heavier tails.